# Spark HiveContext apply IN operation using sql method

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I have an employee hive table with column Name , Department , City and i want to retrieve the data based on names of the employee using IN operation in HiveContext.sql() function but it is throwing pyspark.Analysis Exception.please look at example below.

employee table:

```
Name   Department  City
Ram     FDE        Mumbai
Ramesh  CTZ        Pune
Suraj   FDE        Chennai
Varun   CTZ        Delhi
```

Query :

```
SELECT * from employee WHERE Name in ('Ramesh' , 'Varun')
```

code snippet from spark program:

```
namesList= ['Ramesh' , 'Varun']
data = HiveContext.sql('SELECT * from employee WHERE Name in ({namesList})'.format(namesList = namesList))
```

I tried to modify and pass the strings instead of list but the error remains same

```
Error:pyspark.AnalysisException : structType field
```

please help me on this and suggest me if i'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of square brackets from the python list when creating the query - `str(namesList)[1:-1]`

```
data = HiveContext.sql('SELECT * from employee WHERE Name in ({namesList})'.format(namesList = str(namesList)[1:-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace 
this

```
data = HiveContext.sql('SELECT * from employee WHERE Name in ({namesList})'.format(namesList = namesList))
```

with this

```
data = HiveContext.sql("SELECT * from employee WHERE Name in ({namesList})".format(namesList = "'"+"','".join(namesList)+"'"))
```

You need to pass the string not list.